# xcode : failed to connect to github.com： Operation timed out （-1）

Tags: xcode, git, github, xcode15

I can use **Git** in the **terminal** to push my local XCode project to **GitHub**, But I cannot perform the same push or clone operation in **xcode**,i want to know why and how to solve this problem.

[xcode push error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMV1x.png)

I used xcode to learn C++ and wanted to use GitHub to store my code, so I searched for many tutorial videos on YouTube to set it up, but it just couldn't push successfully.

I use a VPN proxy, Some people say it may work to use the command "git config -- global http. proxy"http://127.0.0.1:7890 ” ,but it doesn't work.

Here are some settings for my xcode.

[xcode setting 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3XW9.png)

[xcode setting 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xw7JA.png)

[xcode setting 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKF1F.png)

[xcode setting 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lsl0V.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.